# What's the formula for the future value of continuous compounded interest with an initial amount and annuity/monthly payments/investments?

Tags: investing, compound-interest

I know the formula for continuous compounded interest with monthly payments/investment is this,

```
p = monthly payment
i = interest per year
c = compounded times per year
t = times compounded

FV = p((1+i/c)^t - 1) / (i/c)
```

But to have it start with an initial amount is what's puzzling me.

For example, I'd like to start with $1000, with a monthly payment/investment of $100 and monthly compounded interest of 8% annual (so 0.08/12 since it's monthly).

What is the formula to get this future value at t amount of times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretend the initial balance is in a separate account. Just figure what the balance of that account would be each month. Then add it to the balance of the first account.

Comment: Well, I want to include the compounded interest on the initial amount. Just adding it wouldn't do that. 1000 + (100 monthly investments compounded monthly) is different than (1000 + 100 monthly investments) compounded monthly.

Comment: But the formula is (1000 compounded monthly)+(100 monthly investments compounded monthly)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Yeah, that works. I can get the formula for both accounts, then add them together. Thanks!